# Can Hom_gp(G,H) fail to be representable for affine algebraic groups?

Tags: algebraic-groups, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $G$ and $H$ be affine algebraic groups over a scheme $S$ of characteristic 0 and let $\textbf{Hom}_{S,gp}(G,H)$ be the functor $T \mapsto \text{Hom}\_{T,gp}(G,H)$

> **Theorem** (SGA 3, expose XXIV, 7.3.1(a)): Suppose G is reductive. Then 
>   $\textbf{Hom}_{S,gp}(G,H)$ is representable by a scheme.

Can this fail if $G$ is not reductive? I worked out a few example with $G = \mathbb{G}_a$, but they were representable.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

$\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{G}_a, \mathbb{G}_m)$ is not representable.

Let $R$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra. I claim that $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{G}_a, \mathbb{G}_m)(\operatorname{Spec} R)$ is {Nilpotent elements of $R$}. Intuitively, all homs are of the form $x\mapsto e^{nx}$ with $n$ nilpotent.

More precisely, the schemes underlying $\mathbb{G}_a$ and $\mathbb{G}_m$ are
$\operatorname{Spec} R[x]$ and $\operatorname{Spec} R[y, y^{-1}]$ respectively. Any hom of schemes is of the form $y \mapsto \sum f_i x^i $for some $f_i$ in $R$. The condition that this be a hom of groups says that
$\sum f_k (x_1+x_2)^k = (\sum f_i x_1^i)(\sum f_j x_2^j)$. Expanding this, $f_{i+j}/(i+j)! = f_i/i! f_j/j!$. So every hom is of the form $f_i = n^i/i!$, and n must be nilpotent so that the sum will be finite.

Now, let's see that this isn't representable. For any positive integer $k$, let $R_k = C[t]/t^k$. The map $x \mapsto e^{tx}$ is in $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{G}_a, \mathbb{G}_m)(\operatorname{Spec} R_k)$ for every $k$. However, if $R$ is the inverse limit of the $R_k$, there is no corresponding map in $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{G}_a, \mathbb{G}_m)(\operatorname{Spec} R)$. So the functor is not representable.

Comment: "Characteristic zero" here should be interpreted to mean "$\mathbb{Q}$-algebra," I guess.

Comment: "n must by nilpotent" → "$x$ must be nilpotent", I think.

Comment: @LSpice No, I think "$n$ is nilpotent" is correct. You have a unital ring homomorphism $R[y,y^{-1}]\to R[x]$, mapping $y$ to an element $\sum_{i\ge 0}f_ix^i$; this element must be inversible and this is equivalent to: $f_0$ is inversible in $R$ and $f_i$ is nilpotent for all $i\ge 1$. (Then the condition of being a Hopf algebra homomorphism implies the given formula, namely $f_i=f_1^i/i!$, with $f_1$ nilpotent.)

Comment: @YCor, ah, you are [right](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4062/can-hom-gpg-h-fail-to-be-representable-for-affine-algebraic-groups/4105#comment1126453_4105).  I thought the $n$ in $f_i = n^i/i!$ was an integer; it didn't occur to me that it was a ring element.

Comment: I am confused now about the $x$ nilpotent vs $n$ nilpotent business. The way it is written now in the post it looks like the homomorphism is very picky and only accepts nilpotent elements as input. But that is not how homormorphisms are supposed to work, right? The domain should be the whole group

Comment: It seems to me that the original formulation was the right one and the edit introduced an error. But then again I know virtually nothing about this subject, so it seems likely that I am wrong. Either way I would be happy if someone could clarify this

Comment: @Vincent Sorry for introducing more confusion. I did, indeed, want $n$ nilpotent.

Answer (score 20):

There is a reasonable salvage, at least if the base scheme is a field: Hom(G,H) is a direct limit of representable subfunctors.  See Lemma A.8.13 in the book "pseudo-reductive groups" (where it is used to prove that the scheme-theoretic fixed locus for a linearly reductive group acting on a connected reductive group is always reductive (possibly disconnected) provided the base is a field.